# duckdb Pandas like resample time series data in

Tags: sql, duckdb

Data sample

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

```
select * from t;
```

| time | num |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-21 13:01:00 | 1 |
| 2023-05-21 13:02:00 | 2 |
| 2023-05-21 13:03:00 | 3 |
| 2023-05-21 13:04:00 | 4 |
| 2023-05-21 13:05:00 | 5 |
| 2023-05-21 13:06:00 | 6 |
| 2023-05-21 13:07:00 | 7 |
| 2023-05-21 13:08:00 | 8 |
| 2023-05-21 13:09:00 | 9 |
| 2023-05-21 13:10:00 | 10 |
| 2023-05-21 13:11:00 | 11 |

```
select time_bucket(INTERVAL '5 min',time) as time,max(num)from t group by time_bucket(INTERVAL '5 min',time);
```

| time | max(num) |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-21 13:00:00 | 4 |
| 2023-05-21 13:05:00 | 9 |
| 2023-05-21 13:10:00 | 11 |

In the result the time interval starts from 00-04,05-10.

What I want is 01-05,06-10.
The data I want.

| time | max(num) |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-21 13:05:00 | 5 |
| 2023-05-21 13:10:00 | 10 |

Answer (score 0):

In DuckDB:

You can use [WINDOW functions](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/window_functions.html) to do computations over different "windows" of the data.

In your example, to compute the 5 minute maximum value of data with 1 minute granularity, you could do this with a WINDOW clause of: `OVER (ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`. But, since there might be gaps in the data, it's better to use: `OVER (ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '4 minutes' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`

Working Solution:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TABLE daterandom AS
SELECT * 
    FROM 
        range('2023-05-21 13:00:00'::timestamp, '2023-05-21 14:00:00'::timestamp, interval 1 minute) t(dt)
    POSITIONAL JOIN
        (select x, random() r from range(60) r(x)) 
;

with window_data as (
    SELECT dt, 
        max(x) over (order by dt RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '4 minutes' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
        max(r) over (order by dt RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '4 minutes' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
    FROM daterandom)
SELECT * FROM window_data
    -- every 5th minute
    WHERE extract(minutes from dt) % 5 = 0
    ;
```

Comment: the `% 5 == 0` might drop all rows if, as you say yourself, there is missing data every five minutes

Answer (score 0):

`time_bucket` has an [optional third argument](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/timestamp#timestamp-functions) that lets you set the anchor of the binning. You can use either an interval or the first timestamp:

```sql
SELECT 
    time_bucket(INTERVAL 5 MINUTE, time, '2023-05-21 13:01:00'::TIMESTAMP) AS bin,
    max(num)
FROM t 
GROUP BY ALL
----
2023-05-21 13:01:00 5
2023-05-21 13:06:00 10
2023-05-21 13:11:00 11

SELECT 
    time_bucket(INTERVAL 5 MINUTE, time, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AS bin,
    max(num)
FROM t 
GROUP BY ALL
----
2023-05-21 13:01:00 5
2023-05-21 13:06:00 10
2023-05-21 13:11:00 11
```

Also, you don't need to repeat the grouping function expression - DuckDB supports both Postgres' [grouping by degrees](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-select.html) (1, 2...) and [their own `ALL` syntax](https://duckdb.org/2022/05/04/friendlier-sql.html) that groups by all non-aggregate functions.

But it sounds like what you need is the [`arg_max`](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/aggregates.html) function. The `arg_min/max` aggregates can help you avoid a number of common windowing operations. You then just need to strip out the bin column (as it is redundant):

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT '2023-05-21 13:00:00'::TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL (num) MINUTE AS time, num
    FROM range(1,12) r(num)
), bucketed AS (
    SELECT 
        time_bucket(INTERVAL 5 MINUTE, time, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AS bin,
        arg_max(time, num) AS time,
        max(num) AS num,
    FROM t 
    GROUP BY ALL
)
SELECT time, num
FROM bucketed;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The interval I want is from 01-05 so the max of num for 2023-05-21 13:05:00 is 5. I tried `SELECT 
    time_bucket(INTERVAL 5 MINUTE, time, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AS bin,
    max(num)
FROM t 
GROUP BY ALL`. The max number is correct (5),but the time is wrong(2023-05-21 13:01:00 instead 2023-05-21 13:05:00).

Comment: That's what the `arg_max` call is for. The query in your comment leaves out that function.

Comment: I think @colinshen might simply want `time_bucket(INTERVAL 5 MINUTE, time, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) + INTERVAL 4 MINUTE` (which would produce different results than the `arg_max` if `num` weren't ordered. However, `time_bucket` uses left-closed&right-open intervals labeled with the left-close, and I think he really wants left-open&right-closed intervals labeled with the right-close, and I don't think there is a solution to that (unless his data is actually on minute boundaries like in the MWE)